# Java clock error

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I was making a clock, which displays time in Java, I will show the code below:

```java
public class MyApp extends javax.swing.JFrame {

      int timeRun = 0;  

    /**
     * Creates new form MyApp
     */
    public MyApp() {
        initComponents();
              System.out.println("We'll start here!");

        new Thread ()
        {
            public void Run(){

                while(timeRun == 0)
                {
                    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

                    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                    int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    int sec = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    int AM_PM = cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

                    String time = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
                    System.out.print(time);
                    System.out.print("We'll end here!");

                }
            }

        }.start();

   }
```

I have a JLabel, and the other components needed for this JFrame to work.

I also have main set up, although you can't see it in the example above
My issue is, that I can't get a value from time, nor can I print "We'll end here" inside the Run, I'm new to Java, so any help would be much appreciated.

My console prints this:

```
run:
We'll start here!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Comment: If you need to periodically update the UI, you should be using a `javax.swing.Timer`, which will execute "ticks" within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: not sure if it´s related or not but it should be run(), not Run()

Comment: No need to yell "SOLVED" in title. This isn't a discussion forum. This is a true Q&A site. You just have to mark an answer accepted. The question will already appear differently in listings and search without the need to alter the title.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't allowed to do so at the time, and I didn't want to waste people's time. Not to mention I've never even used this site before, so please do excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've created a thread, but you haven't overridden the `run` method - instead you've created a `Run` method. Java is case-sensitive. Change this:

```
public void Run() {
    ...
}
```

to this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    ...
}
```

Using `@Override` asks the compiler to validate that you really *are* overriding something - if you'd used that before, you'd have received a compile-time error.

Additionally, I'd recommend implementing `Runnable` and passing that to the `Thread` constructor instead of overriding `run` in `Thread` itself:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
};
new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Again, if you'd implemented the interface instead of creating an anonymous subclass of `Thread`, the compiler would have picked up the problem.

EDIT: As noted in comments, your loop is never-ending, too... but you'll see that when it actually gets as far as running.

Comment: Was just about to add something about the `@Override` annotation; good to see you beat me to it. :)

Comment: Not to mention `timeRun` is never modified in OP's original implementation (at least in the snippet we see), so it's worth mentioning even when `Run` is changed to `run`, the Thread will loop continuously.

Comment: I always turn on the warning in eclipse if you are missing @Override so that you also get warned if you unintentionally override something. Also recommend using SimpleDateFormat instead of manually creating the string.

Answer (score 1):

The thread's method you must ***override*** is **`run`**. Because that's the one you are **inheriting** and which is intented to actually *run* what thread must do.

So:

1. It's all about inheritance.
2. Add `@Override` annotations in such codes. (IDE should have suggested it).
3. Remember Java is case sensitive.
4. Stick to *Camel notation*. In Java, all is supposed to be coded according to it.

   4.1 Classes and Interfaces are supposed to start with capital letters.
   4.2 Attributes and methods are supposed to start with small letters.

You should have done:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: I think you already got an idea about what a Thread is but if you're not I suggest you reading a bit about it for coding such applications ;)